# Android OnTouchEvent fires 3 times

Tags: android, touch-event

I am trying to implement onTouchEvent on MapView to update geopoints but when I touch a screenwith the catching only ACTION_UP, it fires 3 times. How to execute my code once in this condition?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.e("Touch", Integer.toString(event.getAction()));
        //All 3 fires has index 1 that concern to ACTION_UP
        //Below will be AsyncTask call
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the method-signature, I take it that your example is from an overwritten `Overlay`? If so, it's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29) states:

> **Returns**: **True if the tap was handled** by this overlay.

This is standard android behavior for almost every event (onTouch, onKey, etc). If the event was handled (in your case, you started your AsyncTask), you should return `true`, so Android knows that it has been handled.

Since you are always returning `false`, the framework does not know if it has been handled and dispatches the Action further down the event-handling chain. I'm not sure why it's exactly three times.

So, if you successfully handled the event, return `true`.